# Use MYSQL to create a summary

Tags: mysql

I need to `SELECT` the following data from one of my database tables:

```
EmployeeCode, TransactionDate, WeekEndingDate, COUNT(Hrs)
```

I need to group the results of this by `EmployeeCode` and by `TransactionDate`.

An example of the results i expect would be the following:

```
EMPCODE | TRNDATE    | WED        | HRS

0000    |2016-03-24  |2016-03-24  |8
0000    |2016-03-23  |2016-03-24  |10
0001    |2016-03-24  |2016-03-24  |7.5
0001    |2016-03-23  |2016-03-24  |6
0002    |2016-03-24  |2016-03-24  |8
0002    |2016-03-23  |2016-03-24  |9
```

How would I go about achieving this?

Thus Far I have the following:

```
    SELECT empcode, 
       trndate, 
       weekendingdate, 
       Sum(hrs) 
FROM   timeentries 
GROUP  BY trndate 
ORDER  BY empcode ASC
```

But this only groups by dates I need to see a line for each employee and for each date.

Tables Structure is as follows:

```
  `ID` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `EmpCode` varchar(12) DEFAULT NULL,
  `Project` varchar(12) DEFAULT NULL,
  `Hrs` decimal(18,2) DEFAULT NULL,
  `WeekEndingDate` date DEFAULT NULL,
  `TrnDate` date DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`ID`)
```

Comment: What is your table name? What sort of data do you expect to see in that table?

Comment: Table Name is TimeEntries

Comment: could you please tell us table structure, key...etc with sample data, then it will be easy to frame query for you.

Comment: Also is that query working? because i think u need to put all the columns in group by not only trnsdate...

Comment: Have added to question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is the Code the worked for me:

```
     SELECT 
           ID,               
           CONCAT(EmpCode, '-', EmpName) as Emp,
           TrnDate,  
           Sum(Hrs) 
    FROM   TimeEntries
    WHERE  WeekEndingDate = '$ActiveWeek' 
    GROUP  BY 
           TrnDate,
           EmpCode
    ORDER  BY empcode ASC
```

$ActiveWeek is a php variable containing the currently open week of work.